# Operating on parsed data with attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

### Background

I've written a logfile parser using attoparsec. All my smaller parsers succeed, as does the composed final parser. I've confirmed this with [tests](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-attoparsec-0.1.0.1/docs/Test-Hspec-Attoparsec.html). But I'm stumbling over performing operations with the parsed stream.

### What I've tried

I started by trying to pass the successfully parsed input to a function. But all the seems to get is `Done ()`, which I'm presuming means the logfile has been consumed by this point.

```
prepareStats :: Result Log -> IO ()
prepareStats r =
case r of
    Fail _ _ _ -> putStrLn $ "Parsing failed"
    Done _ parsedLog -> putStrLn "Success" -- This now has a [LogEntry] array. Do something with it.

main :: IO ()
main = do
[f] <- getArgs
logFile <- B.readFile (f :: FilePath)
let results = parseOnly parseLog logFile
putStrLn "TBC"
```

### What I'm trying to do

I want to accumulate some stats from the logfile as I consume the input. For example, I'm parsing response codes and I'd like to count how many 2** responses there were and how many 4/5** ones. I'm parsing the number of bytes each response returned as Ints, and I'd like to efficiently sum these (sounds like a `foldl'`?). I've defined a data type like this:

```
data Stats = Stats {
    successfulRequestsPerMinute :: Int
  , failingRequestsPerMinute    :: Int
  , meanResponseTime            :: Int
  , megabytesPerMinute          :: Int
  } deriving Show
```

And I'd like to constantly update that as I parse the input. But the part of performing operations as I consume is where I got stuck. So far `print` is the only function I've successfully passed output to and it showed the parsing is succeeding by returning `Done` before printing the output.

My main parser(s) look like this:

```
parseLogEntry :: Parser LogEntry
parseLogEntry = do
ip <- logItem
_ <- char ' '
logName <- logItem
_ <- char ' '
user <- logItem
_ <- char ' '
time <- datetimeLogItem
_ <- char ' '
firstLogLine <- quotedLogItem
_ <- char ' '
finalRequestStatus <- intLogItem
_ <- char ' '
responseSizeB <- intLogItem
_ <- char ' '
timeToResponse <- intLogItem
return $ LogEntry ip logName user time firstLogLine finalRequestStatus responseSizeB timeToResponse

type Log = [LogEntry]

parseLog :: Parser Log
parseLog = many $ parseLogEntry <* endOfLine
```

### Desired outcome

I want to pass each parsed line to a function that will update the above data type. Ideally I want this to be very memory efficient because it'll be operating on large files.

Comment: Please edit your question and make your code self-contained. In particular, add the required import statements. Also, have you considered using the applicative style for `parseLogEntry`? It wouldn't affect performance, but it would readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each log entry is exactly one line, here's a simpler solution:

```
do loglines <- fmap BS.lines $ BS.readfile "input-file.log"
   foldl' go initialStats loglines
   where
     go stats logline = 
        case parseOnly yourParser logline of
          Left e  -> error $ "oops: " ++ e
          Right r -> let stats' = ... combine r with stats ...
                     in stats'
```

Basically you are just reading the file line-by-line and calling `parseOnly` on each line and accumulating the results.

Comment: I *think* I understand this but I'm not sure. I'm interpreting this as: 1 - get array (I presume lazily) of lines from the input file; 2 - setup a foldl' using a function 'go', with an initial value of 'initialStats', which I presume I'd initialise as Stats record with all 0s; 3 - define the function 'go', which parses each line and either returns an error or calls a function that updates the initialStats record; 4 - I don't know what in stats' is doing here. Am I understanding correctly up to the point at 4 where I don't? If not, are you able to clarify? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You've got it right. `stats'` is the updated version of `stats`. For instance, if `stats` is just a Int which is counting the number of lines parsed, then you can define `stats'` as `stats+1`. Folds are the way you loop in Haskell while carrying around a piece of state from iteration to iteration. Also see [this wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') for more information about strictness and folds.

Comment: fwiw I modified this for use with the standard streaming libraries below.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make your unit of parsing a single log entry rather than a list of log entries.

It's not pretty, but here is an example of how to interleave parsing and processing:

(Depends on `bytestring`, `attoparsec` and `mtl`)

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, FlexibleContexts #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as A
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 hiding (takeWhile)
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

aWord :: Parser BS.ByteString
aWord = skipSpace >> A.takeWhile isAlphaNum

getNext :: MonadState [a] m => m (Maybe a)
getNext = do
  xs <- get
  case xs of
    [] -> return Nothing
    (y:ys) -> put ys >> return (Just y)

loop iresult =
  case iresult of
    Fail _ _ msg  -> error $ "parse failed: " ++ msg
    Done x' aword -> do lift $ process aword; loop (parse aWord x')
    Partial _     -> do
      mx <- getNext
      case mx of
        Just y  -> loop (feed iresult y)
        Nothing -> case feed iresult BS.empty of
                     Fail _ _ msg  -> error $ "parse failed: " ++ msg
                     Done x' aword -> do lift $ process aword; return ()
                     Partial _     -> error $ "partial returned"  -- probably can't happen

process :: Show a => a -> IO ()
process w = putStrLn $ "got a word: " ++ show w

theWords = map BS.pack [ "this is a te", "st of the emergency ", "broadcasting sys", "tem"]


main = runStateT (loop (Partial (parse aWord))) theWords
```

Notes:

- We parse a `aWord` at a time and call `process` after each word is recognized.
- Use `feed` to feed the parser more input when it returns a `Partial`.
- Feed the parser an empty string when there is no more input left.
- When `Done` is return, process the recognized word and continue with `parse aWord`.
- `getNext` is just an example of a monadic function which gets the next unit of input. Replace it with your own version - i.e. something that reads the next line from a file.

## Update

Here is a solution using `parseWith` as @dfeuer suggested:

```
noMoreInput = fmap null get

loop2 x = do
  iresult <- parseWith (fmap (fromMaybe BS.empty) getNext) aWord x
  case iresult of
    Fail _ _ msg  -> error $ "parse failed: " ++ msg
    Done x' aword -> do lift $ process aword;
                        if BS.null x'
                           then do b <- noMoreInput
                                   if b then return ()
                                        else loop2 x'
                           else loop2 x'
    Partial _     -> error $ "huh???" -- this really can't happen

main2 = runStateT (loop2 BS.empty) theWords
```

Comment: It is definitely possible, in general, to get a `Partial`, feed it some more input, and get another `Partial`. The easiest way to run an `attoparsec` parser (if you're not using something like `pipes` or `conduit`, is to use [`parseWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#g:5), which will never return `Partial`.

Comment: Added solution based on `parseWith`.

Answer (score 2):

This is properly done with a streaming library

```
main = do
  f:_ <- getArgs
  withFile f ReadMode $ \h -> do
       result <- foldStream $ streamProcess $ streamHandle h
       print result
where
 streamHandle  = undefined
 streamProcess = undefined
 foldStream    = undefined
```

where the blanks can be filled by any streaming library, e.g.

```
 import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
 import Pipes
 import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
 import Pipes.Group (folds)
 import qualified Control.Foldl as L
 import Control.Lens (view) -- or import Lens.Simple (view), or whatever

 streamHandle =  Pipes.ByteStream.fromHandle :: Handle -> Producer ByteString IO ()
```

in that case we might then divide the labor further thus:

```
 streamProcess :: Producer ByteString m r -> Producer LogEntry m r
 streamProcess p =  streamLines p >-> lineParser

 streamLines :: Producer ByteString m r -> Producer ByteString m r
 streamLines p = L.purely fold L.list (view (Pipes.ByteString.lines p)) >-> P.map B.toStrict

 lineParser :: Pipe ByteString LogEntry m r
 lineParser = P.map (parseOnly line_parser) >-> P.concat -- concat removes lefts
```

(This is slightly laborious because pipes is sensible persnickety about accumulating lines, and memory generally: we are just trying to get a producer of individual strict bytestring lines, and then to convert that into a producer of parsed lines, and then to throw out bad parses, if there are any. With io-streams or conduit, things will be basically the same, and that particular step will be easier.)

We are now in a position to fold over our `Producer LogEntry IO ()`. This can be done explicitly using `Pipes.Prelude.fold`, which makes a strict left fold. Here we will just cop the structure from user5402

```
 foldStream str = P.fold go initial_stats id
  where
   go stats_till_now new_entry = undefined
```

If you get used to the use of the `foldl` library and the application of a fold to a Producer with `L.purely fold some_fold`, then you can build `Control.Foldl.Fold`s for your LogEntries out of components and slot in different requests as you please.

If you use `pipes-attoparsec` and include the newline bit in your parser, then you can just write

```
 handleToLogEntries :: Handle -> Producer LogEntry IO ()
 handleToLogEntries h = void $ parsed my_line_parser (fromHandle h) >-> P.concat
```

and get the `Producer LogEntry IO ()` more directly.  (This ultra-simple way of writing it will, however, stop at a bad parse; dividing on lines first will be faster than using attoparsec to recognize newlines.) This is very simple with io-streams too, you would write something like

```
import qualified System.IO.Streams as Streams

io :: Handle -> IO ()
io h = do  
    bytes <- Streams.handleToInputStream h
    log_entries <- Streams.parserToInputStream my_line_parser bytes
    fold_result <- Stream.fold go initial_stats log_entries
    print fold_result
```

or to keep with the structure above:

```
 where 
  streamHandle = Streams.handleToInputStream
  streamProcess io_bytes = 
      io_bytes >>= Streams.parserToInputStream my_line_parser
  foldStream io_logentries =
      log_entries >>= Stream.fold go initial_stats
```

Either way, `my_line_parser` should return a `Maybe LogEntry` and should recognize the newline.